# what is the use of rounds in css3 border image?

Tags: html, css

[the border when round 10 is added....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snVvt.jpg) [border when round 30 is added....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOoPq.jpg)i have come across a CSS3 property border-image,it adds the image as the border by slicing the image and adding corners with repeating middle images.There is **rounds** which i been analyzing for 30min ,i couldn't figure out how it works BELOW is the css fragment.

```
{
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    padding: 15px;
    -webkit-border-image: url(border.png) 30 round; 
    -o-border-image: url(border.png) 30 round; 
    border-image: url(border.png) 30 round;
}
```

i have included the images of 10round and 30round and original image.

Comment: did you use border-radius:4px property?

Comment: yes add rounded border on all sides by 4px .border radius is different .

Comment: This ***[link](https://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/)*** can help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `round` value mentioned in the `border-image` is shorthand for `border-image-repeat`.

[**According to MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image-repeat), The `round` value in `border-image-repeat` means:

> Keyword indicating that the image must be repeated until it fills the gap between the two borders. If the image doesn't fit after being repeated for an integral number of times, the image is rescaled to fit.

and always follow MDN for authored documentation.